# SharePoint 2019 cannot credential on Chrome 80+ versions

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, chrome, multifactor-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2019 single farm. I did cumulative updated until July 2022 CU.

After then occurred this issue. I am using windows and form base authentication.

Comment: Is it looping back when you attemp to sign it ?

Comment: No.When I try to authenticate with windows user its throw error.I added ULS log error to  below;     -The identity is not in format we recognize. IdentityName: 'INTRANET/testuser'.     -The value is neither a claim user name nor a claim user name suffix. Value: 'INTRANET\testuser'.

Comment: So it is only happening in Chrome, right ? the other browsers works fine ?

Comment: Yes other browsers works fine.

Comment: check my suggested solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft added a fix in the cumulative update to deal with changes Chrome made with cookie security (Chrome started disallowing cross-domain cookie requests, unless the cookies were explicitly marked).

For the fix, Microsoft only took HTTPS connections into account - and as a result broke any forms based authentication that was running on HTTP only (no HTTPS/SSL).

The easiest way to fix the problem is to host SharePoint with HTTPS/SSL, and your forms based authentication will start working again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added HTTPS/SSL, the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

1. Go to SharePoint Admin Center > Web Applications > Authentication Providers The
2. Tick the "**Enable Windows Authentication**" option,
3. UNTICK the "**Integrated Windows authentication**"

Works on my SharePoint 2019.

Comment: I tried it but didn't works. My farm version is: 16.0.10390.20000-September 2022  , Chrome version is: 96.0.4664 and Form Based Authentication is enabled.(When I change Form Based Authentication to disable it works fine )